# Image search in Lucene using Java api

Tags: lucene

Hi I trying to implement Lucene search on Image. I found some article but not convening. can any body suggest how to store the image on Lucene and able to search using Lucene java API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you have on hand? only images or images with some metadata like tags, titles, description etc. If you have text base metadata then your life will be easy, if you requirement is to search image by image data (color, texture, characteristics) you can checkout LIRE (http://www.lire-project.net/).

For more advanced image search you should have some offline system where you pre-process image and generate data related to image tags, title etc and index this data for search. For pre-processing images you will get tons of open source image processing libraries (like OpenCV).